# Trying to make a simple Makefile fails

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 files, `main.c`, `lists.c`, and `lists.h`.

Im trying to write a Makefile with all the files are in the same directory:

```
maman21: lists.c lists.h main.c
    gcc -g -Wall -ansi main.c -o maman21 -lm
```

going to the folder through terminal and using `make` shows me this message:

```
gcc -g -Wall -ansi main.c -o maman21 -lm
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_linkedListWay",
referenced from:
      _main in main-C9dUT4.o   "_reallocWay", referenced from:
      _main in main-C9dUT4.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
see invocation)
make: *** [maman21] Error 1
```

`reallocWay` and `linkedListWay` are to functions I'm using in the file.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You've failed to include the `lists.c` file in the compiler invocation so it doesn't get built.

It should be:

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -ansi
LDLIBS=-lm

maman21: main.o lists.o

main.o:  main.c

lists.o: lists.c lists.h
```

The above uses implicit Makefile rules, it "knows" how to convert a C file to an object (`.o`) file.

Also, is it normal for Clang to be called `gcc`?

Comment: OS X provides a `gcc` binary that is actually `clang`.

Comment: Where does the gcc goes?
sorry for the stupid question, it seems it only creates the object files and doesnt run them